# For combobox cells in JTables, how do I detect which combobox (which row) is being activated in the listener?

Tags: java, swing, combobox, jtable

```
private void populatePrivate(JTable jtable, TableCellEditor tce) {
String column[] = {"Cell 1", "Cell 2", "Cell 3"};
String items[] = {"Combo Item 1", "Combo Item 2", "Combo Item 3"};
mdl.addColumn("Cells", column);        
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(items);
        comboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Row:");
            }
        });
    }
    jtable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox));
```

The question is, when the `itemStateChange` listener is fired, how do I figure out which row of cells it is being fired from? As far as I can tell, using `e.getSource()` provides no way of figuring out which row the `comboBox` that is being used is coming from.

Comment: can't you ask the JTable what the selected row is?

Comment: Ah, I'm dumb! For some reason I thought it wouldn't pass through to the overridden section

Comment: Why are you attempting to add an ItemListener to a combo box being used as an editor? I'm sure there is a better solution.